# What happened to array-shift.com (Drupal Stackoverflow Clone)

Tags: community-official-site

It's interesting that there is no (recent) Drupal implementation of SO-like features.  I (and others) have a need to have an SO clone that has areas for private data (corporate owned), so we cannot use SO or the StackExchange engine.  I had high hopes for http://drupal.org/project/arrayshift, but it's fallen into disuse (and the demo site has been down for months).

Any suggested alternatives?  We've looked at OSQA and Question2Answer, and both seem like an annoying integration mess for user profile information.

Comment: There is an effort to provide a similar feature under support.drupal.org, see http://www.binaryredneck.net/node/175 and http://drupal.org/sandbox/HedgeMage/1088372. Wondering if this question should be moved to meta, as it is not really a drupal question but a question about this site...

Answer (score 13):

What "happened" is what commonly happens to an idea that is generally solid but not (yet) popular: it's not being used and therefore not being actively maintained.

The best way to combat "disuse" is to use it. Create your own sandbox copy and start improving it. Ask Eaton for permission to take over the module and he'll give it to you.

Answer (score 7):

A fair portion of the functionality in arrayshift has been implemented by the Answers project.

[drupal.org/project/answers](http://drupal.org/project/answers)

Comment: This looks very promising. I stumbled on this http://www.drupalcommerce.org/questions and though it could be based on the "answers" and "best_answer" Drupal modules. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I set up a site with the ArrayShift modules. I had to go through at least two or three cycles of updating a few of them, and although it created views to display most recent/unanswered/hot/etc questions,  it didn't automatically install a new node type for them. It was frustrating trying to figure that out. (The correct type/machine-readable name for the content type is *question*.)

There's no link in the banner menu to allow you to ask a question like the SE sites have (set in the primary links), but that's aping the SE look and feel too much.

It switches the description for titles on forms for creating content to *What's your programming question? Be descriptive.* regardless if it's actually a question or not.

A book page. *What's your programming question? Be descriptive.*

A blog entry. *What's your programming question? Be descriptive.*

A forum topic. *What's your programming question? Be descriptive.*

It's a tad annoying.

But anyway I've just started playing around with it and the basic functionality is there. There's some things I'll change to suit my preferences for a Q&A site, but I'll say ArrayShift looks pretty useful (once modules are updated) so far.

**EDIT:** Putting in a few questions & trying to answer them, it seems that answers are given using Drupal's comment system, rather than a separate *answer* node. While you have comments for answers in that the comment system permits threading and what-not, it doesn't keep comments for the *?* (which are often necessary as you can see in the typical SE *?*) together with them, visually expressing their relationship.

Also, I haven't been able to figure out how to activate the markdown editor.

Answer (score 1):

Update about the " it's fallen into disuse" (related to ArrayShift) in the question here:
the [ArrayShift distribution](https://www.drupal.org/project/arrayshift) has been in a kind of unsupported status until just recently. However its maintenance status has been changed to "actively maintained" again.

And [I recently did](https://www.drupal.org/node/1049212#comment-9799275) as suggested by @greggles, and Eaton accepted indeed.

The project page now contains a roadmap which includes, among others, these items that I believe are the most urgent to be addressed:

- resolve the current security messages on the project page (for D6).
- provide support for D7 (and D8 later on).

The issues mentioned in the answer from @Huperniketes to this question, should get resolved soon now. Don't hesitate to use the issue queue on D.O for reporting bugs, feature requests, etc, as I am also planning to do to publish all sorts of feature requests I have in mind. As an alternative use Drupal.SE for similar support requests (and ping me about such questions in case I might not have noticed them).

Note: I'm interested in finding out more about the usage, purpose, etc of **array-shift.com**. I've been doing some research on that, but nothing seems to exist anymore. So any feedback on that would be appreciated.

Disclosure: I'm the (new) maintainer of this distribution,
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).